# Rails 4 asset pipeline "Unknown Word" issues with the bootstrap-sass gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have run into a strange issue with the bootstrap-sass gem and (possibly?) CSS compilation. The issue is strange because **it worked just fine in development and production until now**. At first, the issue would arise when I attempted to modify the `application.css.scss` file *at all*, and then after I ran `bundle exec rake assets:clobber` the issue persisted both with and without modifications to the stylesheet.

Here is the "Unknown word" error I'm receiving:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3501ms

ActionView::Template::Error (/Users/blake/workspaces/ruby/mineservers/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss:1:1: Unknown word
// Core variables and mixins
^
@import "bootstrap/variables";
  (in /Users/blake/workspaces/ruby/mineservers/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)):
    2: <html>
    3: <head>
    4:   <%= metamagic title: "Mineservers - Minecraft Server List" %>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", "token-input-facebook", media: "all" %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "jquery.tokeninput" %>
    7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8:
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2307231035075038946_70251395438600'
  app/controllers/servers_controller.rb:16:in `index'
```

If I remove the `@import "bootstrap";` line from my `application.css.scss` file, the error goes away, but the entire application has been built on top of Bootstrap styles and I cannot simply leave them out. I have tried fixing it by completely resetting my `config/environments/development.rb` file to the default one created with a new Rails app, but that did not work either.

I recently rolled out the app to a custom VPS environment (taking it off of Heroku), which required a good amount of configuration to the production settings, but I really don't think it would affect the development environment. Any idea how to fix this?

**Update:** Somehow I fixed the problem. I removed the specific bootstrap-sass version from the Gemfile and ran `bundle install` and the issue miraculously fixed itself. I then added the version (3.3.1) back to the Gemfile and ran bundler again, and the problem is *still* not there. Absolutely unbelievable. I'll leave the question up and unanswered in case somebody that knows what happened comes by.